# strptime error in python "does not match"

Tags: python, date, format, strptime

An error occurred while converting the date format from Python.

#### My Code

```
pubDate = "Thu, 08 Jul 2021 17:34:00 +0900"
pubDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(pubDate, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0900")
```

#### Error Code

```
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 568, in _strptime_datetime
    tt, fraction, gmtoff_fraction = _strptime(data_string, format)
File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.9/lib/python3.9/_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data 'Thu, 08 Jul 2021 18:06:00 +0900' does not match format '%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0900'
```

Comment: If you look at the [documentation for strptime](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) it says that some of the variables are dependent on what locale your OS is running. Could that be the culprit here?

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code, and it works fine, I don't get that error.

```
pubDate = "Thu, 08 Jul 2021 17:34:36 +0900"
pubDate = datetime.strptime(pubDate, "%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0900")

pubDate
Out[6]: datetime.datetime(2021, 7, 8, 17, 34, 36)
```

I removed one `datetime` because of how I imported but that depends on you.
The error might be because `%a` depends of region:

"Because the format depends on the current locale, care should be taken when making assumptions about the output value. Field orderings will vary (for example, “month/day/year” versus “day/month/year”), and the output may contain Unicode characters encoded using the locale’s default encoding (for example, if the current locale is ja_JP, the default encoding could be any one of eucJP, SJIS, or utf-8; use locale.getlocale() to determine the current locale’s encoding)."

I suggest checking your locale tosee if the day name format is correct or different.

More info:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior